# Make an absolute path works in local file

Tags: html, path, absolute-path

We have a web proyect in Coldfusion. All resources are linked with absolute paths, I mean, the paths in the css are like this:

```
.class {background:url(/folder/img/image.png);}
```

And the paths in the HTML are like this:

```
<img src="/folder/img/theimage.png"/>
```

I need to download the files to my local machine, make the changes and upload them again.
To see the changes, I manually remove all the slashes in the downloaded files, then write it again, but I think that should be an easier way to see the pages correctly without make those changes.

Can I put the resources folder in some place to make the absolute path find them?
If that's not the correct way, how can I "see" the files in my local machine (without a localhost) without changing the absolute path once and once again?

Comment: You need a local web server.

Comment: Argh... just what I was fearing :( Thanks at all

Comment: Local web servers are not hard.

Comment: I know, usually I use Appserver, but move the files in my secondary HD to the primery HD to test... it's a bit annoying, well, lazyness, you know, thank you so much anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your local development on a computer with a web server that is configured to be as close to the web server you use in production as possible.

Using a virtual machine (such as VMWare or VirtualBox) makes this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern dev. platforms have HTTP servers that are easy to set up. My favorite has always been Python's. Running it is as simple as `cd`ing to your project directory and running one Python command. You can also easily run multiple servers concurrently on different ports.

Here are some examples with Python v. 2.7.

```
# run server on port 9999
> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9999

# run server as background process on port 3333
> nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3333 > /dev/null &
```

Python 3 has a different syntax, but same idea. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server